# VSCode Extension Debugging Node with WSL

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm attempting to debug a vscode extension in Windows using WSL. It appears as though the prelaunchtask is using the cmd.exe arguments, which causes the prelaunchtask to fail with bash.

> Executing task: npm run watch <
>
> /bin/bash: /d: No such file or directory The terminal process
>   terminated with exit code: 127
>
> Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

Any thoughts how I might force the debug terminal to properly issue the bash arguments?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by manually specifying the shell executable and arguments used by the Extension launch configuration. Assuming you are starting with the [example extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-hello-world#_your-first-extension), you can edit the task for the "npm: watch" script in .vscode/tasks.json, forcing it to launch WSL with no additional arguments.

```
{
    "type": "npm",
    "script": "watch",
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch",
    "isBackground": true,
    "presentation": {
        "reveal": "never"
    },
    "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
    },
    // Force this to use WSL with no additional arguments
    "options": {
        "shell": {
            "executable": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe"
        },
        "args": []
    }
}
```